# Mulesoft s3 csv to json

Tags: json, amazon-s3, mule, dataweave, mulesoft

I am trying to take a csv file that was SFTP to s3 bucket and then I use getObject to get data. It is in the payload in form of string and I call the below but it gives me an error. I am not clear if there is another way to convert to json format.  If I step through and just see what is in the payload the data looks fine. If I do a simple change to json doing following:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload
```

I get a bunch of \n \r characters in the results and it does not work.

My logic in the transform message:

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Strings
output application/json

---

payload filter (substring($.FT_OPPORTUNITY_ID,0,3) == "OPP") map ( payload01 , indexOfPayload01 ) -> {
    STAGE: payload01.STAGE,
    OPPORTUNITY_NAME: payload01.OPPORTUNITY_NAME,
    TOTAL_AUM_VALUE: payload01.TOTAL_AUM_VALUE,
    MA_AUM: payload01.MA_AUM,
    PARTICIPANTS_WITH_A_BALANCE: payload01.PARTICIPANTS_WITH_A_BALANCE,
    REFERRING_PARTNER: payload01.REFERRING_PARTNER,
    MANAGED_ACCOUNT_PROVIDER: payload01.MANAGED_ACCOUNT_PROVIDER,
    QDIA_SELECTION: payload01.QDIA_SELECTION,
    NO_OF_PROPRIETARY_FUNDS: payload01.NO_OF_PROPRIETARY_FUNDS,
    ADVISOR_CONTACT_NAME: payload01.ADVISOR_CONTACT_NAME,
    ADVISOR_FIRM_NAME: payload01.ADVISOR_FIRM_NAME,
    ADVISOR_EMAIL: payload01.ADVISOR_EMAIL,
    PROBABILITY: payload01.PROBABILITY,
    ADVISORY_FIRM: payload01.ADVISORY_FIRM,
    CREATED_DATE: payload01.CREATED_DATE,
    CLOSE_DATE: payload01.CLOSE_DATE,
    TOTAL_VESTWELL_ARR: payload01.TOTAL_VESTWELL_ARR,
    OPPORTUNTIY_OWNER: payload01.OPPORTUNTIY_OWNER,
    OPPORTUNITY_ID: payload01.OPPORTUNITY_ID,
    FT_SALES_TERRITORY: payload01.FT_SALES_TERRITORY,
    CRD: payload01.CRD,
    AS_OF_DATE: payload01.AS_OF_DATE,
    SOURCE_ID: payload01.SOURCE_ID,
    FT_Stage: payload01.FT_Stage,
    FT_Probability: payload01.FT_Probability,
    FT_OPPORTUNITY_ID: payload01.FT_OPPORTUNITY_ID,
    PLAN_ID: payload01.PLAN_ID,
    STATE: payload01.STATE
}
```

error message:

```
""You called the function 'Value Selector' with these arguments: 
  1: String ("S")
  2: Name ("FT_OPPORTUNITY_ID")

But it expects one of these combinations:
  (Array, Name)
  (Array, String)
  (Date, Name)
  (DateTime, Name)
  (LocalDateTime, Name)
  (LocalTime, Name)
  (Object, Name)
  (Object, String)
  (Period, Name)
  (Time, Name)

7| payload filter (substring($.FT_OPPORTUNITY_ID,0,3) == "OPP") map ( payload01 , indexOfPayload01 ) -> {
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Trace:
  at anonymous::criteria (line: 7, column: 27)
  at dw::Core::reduce (line: 2352, column: 9)
  at dw::Core::filter (line: 2351, column: 11)
  at anonymous::filter (line: 7, column: 9)
  at anonymous::map (line: 7, column: 9)
  at anonymous::main (line: 7, column: 62)" evaluating expression: "%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Strings
output application/json

---

payload filter (substring($.FT_OPPORTUNITY_ID,0,3) == "OPP") map ( payload01 , indexOfPayload01 ) -> {
    STAGE: payload01.STAGE,
    OPPORTUNITY_NAME: payload01.OPPORTUNITY_NAME,
    TOTAL_AUM_VALUE: payload01.TOTAL_AUM_VALUE,
    MA_AUM: payload01.MA_AUM,
    PARTICIPANTS_WITH_A_BALANCE: payload01.PARTICIPANTS_WITH_A_BALANCE,
    REFERRING_PARTNER: payload01.REFERRING_PARTNER,
    MANAGED_ACCOUNT_PROVIDER: payload01.MANAGED_ACCOUNT_PROVIDER,
    QDIA_SELECTION: payload01.QDIA_SELECTION,
    NO_OF_PROPRIETARY_FUNDS: payload01.NO_OF_PROPRIETARY_FUNDS,
    ADVISOR_CONTACT_NAME: payload01.ADVISOR_CONTACT_NAME,
    ADVISOR_FIRM_NAME: payload01.ADVISOR_FIRM_NAME,
    ADVISOR_EMAIL: payload01.ADVISOR_EMAIL,
    PROBABILITY: payload01.PROBABILITY,
    ADVISORY_FIRM: payload01.ADVISORY_FIRM,
    CREATED_DATE: payload01.CREATED_DATE,
    CLOSE_DATE: payload01.CLOSE_DATE,
    TOTAL_VESTWELL_ARR: payload01.TOTAL_VESTWELL_ARR,
    OPPORTUNTIY_OWNER: payload01.OPPORTUNTIY_OWNER,
    OPPORTUNITY_ID: payload01.OPPORTUNITY_ID,
    FT_SALES_TERRITORY: payload01.FT_SALES_TERRITORY,
    CRD: payload01.CRD,
    AS_OF_DATE: payload01.AS_OF_DATE,
    SOURCE_ID: payload01.SOURCE_ID,
    FT_Stage: payload01.FT_Stage,
    FT_Probability: payload01.FT_Probability,
    FT_OPPORTUNITY_ID: payload01.FT_OPPORTUNITY_ID,
    PLAN_ID: payload01.PLAN_ID,
    STATE: payload01.STATE
}"."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The payload seems to have an incorrect media type so it is considered a String. You can probably set it as a CSV at the S3 operation by using the attribute outputMimeType="application/csv" or in the transformation parse it with read(): `read(payload,"application/csv")`

Comment: 'code' %dw 2.0
output application/json
---
read(payload,"application/csv")

Comment: The expectation was for you to replace the use of `payload` by that expression to fix the parsing. The rest of the script is up to you.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I didnt want to impact rest of script so I just added an additional transform message with the suggested code.

Comment: You can use as you wish. I provided the method, the implemtation is as you wish. Just notice that if the first transform outputs JSON the second one needs to do the extra work of parsing it. In that case Java is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved based on @aled solution.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
read(payload,"application/csv")
```

Comment: You should accept the original answer, instead of acknowledging it by answering again